# How do I upload files of arbitrary size to mezzanine.core.fields.FileField

Tags: django, mezzanine

The featured image on the mezzanine.blog.models.BlogPost content type is of type mezzanine.core.fields.FileField. When I try to upload a featured image there is a 2.5MB limit on the size of the file. Where is this value defined? I want to increase or remove this restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default limit imposed by django's [FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) setting. Increasing that will solve your problem.

If one wanted to limit the size of `FileField`'s to some value *lower* than the `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE`, they can do so with the `FILEBROWSER_MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE` setting. There is no way to effectively set it higher.